# Изменение элемента связанного с другими JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, menu

Есть у меня такое меню (нашел в инете):

```
<div class='cssmenu'>
          <ul>
             <li class='has-sub'><a href="#"><span>Каталог</span></a>
                <ul>
                  @foreach( $catalog as $item )
                   <li class='has-sub'><a href="#"><img class="catalogimg" src="/img/categories/{{ $item->img }}"><span>{{ $item->name }}</span></a>
                      <ul>
                        @foreach( $item->children as $subitem )
                         <li><a href='/{{ $item->url }}/{{ $subitem->url }}'><img class="catalogimg" src="/img/categories/{{ $subitem->img }}"><span>{{ $subitem->name }}</span></a></li>
                        @endforeach
                      </ul>
                   </li>
                   @endforeach
                </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

Его стили:

```
.cssmenu, .cssmenu ul, .cssmenu ul li, .cssmenu ul li a {
    border: 0 none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.cssmenu {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    width: 280px;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -3px;
}
.cssmenu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    background: rgb(54,170,231); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(54,170,231,1) 0%, rgba(31,160,228,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(54,170,231,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(31,160,228,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(54,170,231,1) 0%,rgba(31,160,228,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(54,170,231,1) 0%,rgba(31,160,228,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(54,170,231,1) 0%,rgba(31,160,228,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(54,170,231,1) 0%,rgba(31,160,228,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#36aae7', endColorstr='#1fa0e4',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border-left: 1px solid #1682ba;
    border-right: 1px solid #1682ba;
    border-top: 1px solid #1682ba;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    z-index: 2;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
.cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
.cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
    background: rgb(31,160,228); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(31,160,228,1) 0%, rgba(25,146,209,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(31,160,228,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(25,146,209,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(31,160,228,1) 0%,rgba(25,146,209,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(31,160,228,1) 0%,rgba(25,146,209,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(31,160,228,1) 0%,rgba(25,146,209,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(31,160,228,1) 0%,rgba(25,146,209,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1fa0e4', endColorstr='#1992d1',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color: #eeeeee;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a,
.cssmenu > ul > li.last > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
.holder {
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
}
.holder:after, .holder:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    width: 6px;
    z-index: 10;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
}
.arr.holder:after, .arr.holder:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition-duration: 500ms;
}
.holder:after {
    border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    top: 17px;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover > span:after,
.cssmenu > ul > li.active > a > span:after,
.cssmenu > ul > li.open > a > span:after {
    border-color: #eeeeee;
}
.holder:before {
    border-left-color: inherit;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 2px;
    border-top-color: inherit;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    top: 18px;
}
.cssmenu ul ul li a {
    background:#49505a;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
    border-left: 1px solid #32373e;
    border-right: 1px solid #32373e;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
    color: #eeeeee;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
.cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
.cssmenu ul ul li.open > a,
.cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #424852;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
}
.cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li:last-child > a,
.cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last > a {
    border-bottom: 0 none;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > a,
.cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last.open > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a {
    border-bottom: 0 none;
}
.cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
    border-left: 2px solid #eeeeee;
    border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 18px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    width: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.arr.cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition-duration: 500ms;
}
.cssmenu ul ul li.active > a:after,
.cssmenu ul ul li.open > a:after,
.cssmenu ul ul li > a:hover:after {
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cssmenu li.has-sub > a').on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('href');
        var element = $(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('open')) {
            element.removeClass('open');
            element.find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('open');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
    });
    $('.cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a').click(function(){
        $('.holder').toggleClass('arr');
    });


    $('.cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a').append('<span class="holder"></span>');
});
```

В общем меню изначально как одна кнопка, а потом раскрывается, имеет 2 уровня вложенности. Через псевдо элементы сделаны стрелочки. При нажатии я хотел сделать, чтобы стрелочка вращалась на 180 градусов, для кнопки я смог сделать, т.к. она одна, а вот для дочерних элементов не получается, если и меняет положение, то все, а не текущий раскрытый список.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$('.cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a').click(function(){
        $('.cssmenu').toggleClass('arr');
    });
```

Вот так получилось, но вращаются все, не силен в JS/JQuery, не знаю как сделать, чтобы только стрелка развернутого элемента вращалась.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно добавить в стили вот этот код

```
.cssmenu > ul > .has-sub.open > a > .holder::before,
.cssmenu > ul > .has-sub.open > a > .holder::after,
.cssmenu .has-sub.open > a::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

И получится следующее:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cssmenu li.has-sub > a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
    var element = $(this).parent('li');
    if (element.hasClass('open')) {
      element.removeClass('open');
      element.find('li').removeClass('open');
      element.find('ul').slideUp();
    } else {
      element.addClass('open');
      element.children('ul').slideDown();
      element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
      element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
      element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
      element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
    }
  });


  $('.cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a').append('<span class="holder"></span>');
});
```

```css
.cssmenu,
.cssmenu ul,
.cssmenu ul li,
.cssmenu ul li a {
  border: 0 none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.cssmenu {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 280px;
  z-index: 2;
  top: -3px;
}

.cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.cssmenu>ul>li>a {
  background: rgb(54, 170, 231);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54, 170, 231, 1) 0%, rgba(31, 160, 228, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(54, 170, 231, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(31, 160, 228, 1)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54, 170, 231, 1) 0%, rgba(31, 160, 228, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54, 170, 231, 1) 0%, rgba(31, 160, 228, 1) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54, 170, 231, 1) 0%, rgba(31, 160, 228, 1) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(54, 170, 231, 1) 0%, rgba(31, 160, 228, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#36aae7', endColorstr='#1fa0e4', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  border-left: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-right: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-top: 1px solid #1682ba;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  z-index: 2;
}

.cssmenu>ul>li>a:hover,
.cssmenu>ul>li.active>a,
.cssmenu>ul>li.open>a {
  background: rgb(31, 160, 228);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(31, 160, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(25, 146, 209, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(31, 160, 228, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(25, 146, 209, 1)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(31, 160, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(25, 146, 209, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(31, 160, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(25, 146, 209, 1) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(31, 160, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(25, 146, 209, 1) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(31, 160, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(25, 146, 209, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1fa0e4', endColorstr='#1992d1', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  color: #eeeeee;
}

.cssmenu>ul>li.open>a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.cssmenu>ul>li:last-child>a,
.cssmenu>ul>li.last>a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}

.holder {
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.holder:after,
.holder:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  width: 6px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}

.arr.holder:after,
.arr.holder:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}

.holder:after {
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  top: 17px;
}

.cssmenu>ul>li>a:hover>span:after,
.cssmenu>ul>li.active>a>span:after,
.cssmenu>ul>li.open>a>span:after {
  border-color: #eeeeee;
}

.holder:before {
  border-left-color: inherit;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  top: 18px;
}

.cssmenu ul ul li a {
  background: #49505a;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-left: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-right: 1px solid #32373e;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
  color: #eeeeee;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a,
.cssmenu ul ul li.open>a,
.cssmenu ul ul li.active>a {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #424852;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.cssmenu ul ul li:first-child>a {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child>a {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
}

.cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li:last-child>a,
.cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li.last>a {
  border-bottom: 0 none;
}

.cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li.open:last-child>a,
.cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li.last.open>a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
}

.cssmenu>ul>li>ul>li.open:last-child>ul>li:last-child>a {
  border-bottom: 0 none;
}

.cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a:after {
  border-left: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  width: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.arr.cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}

.cssmenu ul ul li.active>a:after,
.cssmenu ul ul li.open>a:after,
.cssmenu ul ul li>a:hover:after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}

.cssmenu>ul>.has-sub.open>a>.holder::before,
.cssmenu>ul>.has-sub.open>a>.holder::after,
.cssmenu .has-sub.open>a::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href="#"><span>Каталог</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href="#"><img class="catalogimg" src="/img/categories/{{ $item->img }}"><span>{{ $item->name }}</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='/{{ $item->url }}/{{ $subitem->url }}'><img class="catalogimg" src="/img/categories/{{ $subitem->img }}"><span>{{ $subitem->name }}</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо!